# I want child row for every tr element in angular js

Tags: angularjs, html-table, parent-child

First of all my code:
html

```
    <td class="name">
        <i class="mdi mdi-plus s16" ng-click="childRowToggle($event)"></i>
        <div ng-click="details(assets.code)">{{assets.name}}</div>
        <span class="secondary-text">{{assets.code}}</span>
    </td>

</tr>
<tr data-ng-repeat="assets in vm.employees" class="collapse row{{$index}}">
    <td colspan="5" class="child">
        child row
    </td>
</tr>
```

and my controller

```
 $scope.childRowToggle =  function($event){
     $('#childrow').remove();
           var $this  = $($event.target);
           var $obj =$this.parent().parent();
           console.log($obj.attr('class'));
           $("<tr id='childrow'><td colspan='5'>Dummy Data</td></tr>").insertAfter($obj);

     }
```

now when I press the down arrow 'dummy data' is coming but I want to display the child tr under correspond tr. How can I do this?

Comment: Do not forget to provide the vm.employees list.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you'd like to insert a `<tr>` under the current `<tr>` when the down arrow is clicked. Rather than inserting new html via jQuery in your controller, you could do the following:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="assets in vm.employees">
    <tr ng-init="assets.showChild=false">
        <td class="name">
            <i class="mdi mdi-plus s16" ng-click="assets.showChild=!assets.showChild"></i>
            <div ng-click="details(assets.code)">{{assets.name}}</div>
            <span class="secondary-text">{{assets.code}}</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-show="assets.showChild">
        <td colspan="5" class="child">
            child row
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

HTML doesn't care how many `<tbody>` tags a table has, so you can place your `ng-repeat` on a `<tbody>`. You then insert two rows into the table body, then you set the `ng-click` on your down arrow in the first row to toggle the visibility of the second row in your table body.  Using this method you don't have to worry about inserting new HTML into the table (and deleting it later, when you toggle off the `<tr>`.)

The only thing that you'd probably want to do differently is to add a `showChild` member to `vm.employees` in your controller rather than use the `ng-init` directive on the first `<tr>`

Answer (score 0):

Working effectively in Angular requires unlearning a lot of jQuery habits -- if you find yourself reaching for `.appendChild` or `innerHTML` or etc you're probably on the wrong track.

Never modify the DOM directly in Angular -- at best you're just making life harder for yourself by working against the framework, at worst your changes will get wiped out in the next $digest because Angular doesn't know you've rummaged around in the DOM.

A much better approach is to modify the data and let Angular take care of the view for you -- for example you could have your down arrow add a boolean "showChild" to the appropriate `vm.employee`

```
scope.toggleChildRow(asset) = function() {
  asset.showChild = !asset.showChild;
});
```

and do something like this in your template:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="assets in vm.employee">
  <tr><td ng-click="toggleChildRow(assets)">↓</td>(...normal row...)</tr>
  <tr ng-if="assets.showChild">...child row...</tr>
</tbody>
```

(The weird multiple `<tbody>` thing is an unfortunate but necessary artifact of ng-repeat with tables.)